# how convert int64 to date?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with an INT64 column called ***last_modification_time*** and values are as below:

**1640089029711**

**1640100925628**

I would like to see it in a date format.
`TIMESTAMP_MICROS(last_modification_time)`
convert above values to

**1970-01-19 23:34:49.029711 UTC**

**1970-01-19 23:35:00.925628 UTC**

which definitely is incorrect. Would you please let me know how I can convert to a date format? I am expecting to see a 2021 date as modification dates are mostly 2021 for my data.

**Expected result:** a 2021 date
Thanks

Comment: And what is the result you want to see?

Comment: a 2021/2020 date not 1970

Comment: I am not converting correctly!

Comment: Add the expected result to your question.

Comment: I am not sure how to convert that int to date! I know it should be a 2021 date. I added that to my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert epoch to date in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714205/how-do-you-convert-epoch-to-date-in-bigquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below

```
select last_modification_time, timestamp_millis(last_modification_time)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you, brilliant!